# Weka says 'training and test set are not compatible' when both are the same file

Tags: weka

I'm getting a very odd error from the weka machine learning toolkit:

```
java weka.classifiers.meta.AdaBoostM1 -t train.arff -d tmp.model -c 22 //generates the model
java weka.classifiers.meta.AdaBoostM1 -l tmp.model -T train.arff -p 22 //have the model predict values in the set it was trained on.
```

This produces the message:

```
java.lang.Exception: training and test set are not compatible
        at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:1035)
        at weka.classifiers.Classifier.runClassifier(Classifier.java:312)
        at weka.classifiers.meta.AdaBoostM1.main(AdaBoostM1.java:779)
```

But of course, the input files are the same... Any suggestions?

Comment: Solved, after a fashion, with 

java weka.classifiers.meta.AdaBoostM1 -t smallTrain.arff -T test.arff -c 22 -p 0

Not a nice solution though, since it doesn't allow for reuse of models. Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Weka is complaining when the class variable does not consist of the same number of classes, e.g. when you training data consists of the classes {a,b,c} and the testing data (loaded later) only has {a,c}. In that case Weka just throws that nice exception :)
Maybe you find a solution in the Weka source code or by loading your data sets with the Weka Explorer. The latter one tells you how the data set is looking like when it is loaded...

Comment: This often happens when you are importing CSV files or something else but when using ARFF files the description attribute in the header should contain all the cases in the same order.